# PHP: How do i test the time which it takes to do a query?

Tags: php

How do i test the speed of a database call from PHP?

I interested in testing how many miliseconds it takes my script to call the database with a query and gets the result. For example how many milisecond would the query below take to execute:

SELECT * FROM customers OrderBy customer_id

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$q = "SELECT foo FROM BAR";
$start = microtime(true);
$res = query($q);
$end = microtime(true);

echo "Query took " . ( $end-$start) . " seconds";
```

Comment: Actually, microtime() returns microseconds, not seconds.

Comment: Passing true as the first argument makes microtime return the time as a float.  Expected output would be "Query took X.Y seconds"